# how to use <select> in while loop with php

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, while-loop, html-select

I have a result set from a query (4 columns).

```
$res = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)
```

i used this result set in while loop to display it in html table.
now, i want to add all 2nd column values of result set in `<select>` without using above result set. (cause i used it in while loop/ don't want to fetch again)

so, i did this.

```
<select>
     <option value=""> --Select-- </option>
     <?php
     while ($id = $query->fetchColumn(1)) 
     {

              echo "<option value='".$id."'>'".$id."'</option>";
      }
      ?>
      </select>
```

but it doesnt work. how?

Comment: In the while loop, try this: `print_r($id);`. What do you get then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Do not use `<select>` in while loop with php

but use it in `foreach` instead. Get your data first,

```
$data = $query->fetchAll();
```

and then use this data to output

```
<select>
    <option value=""> --Select-- </option>
    <?php foreach($data as $row): ?>
    <option><?=$row['id']?></option>
    <?php endforeach ?>
</select>
```

Comment: and why so not to use while?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have already looped through the results once, but then tried to loop again.  If you don't reset the cursor, then there won't be anything to fetch -- you'll already be at the end of your results.

[Resetting array pointer in PDO results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9437214/resetting-array-pointer-in-pdo-results)