# How to access column-values before fetching?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I need the values of one columns before fetching the query. Something like this:

```
// mytable
+----+-------+
| id | codes |
+----+-------+
| 1  | 102   |
| 2  | 64    |
| 3  | 563   |
| 4  | 79    |
+----+-------+
```

My query:

```
$db = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mydb", "root", "");
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$sth = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM mytable");
$sth->execute();

/* I need to those numbers in the codes-column as an array in here */

while ($results = $sth->fetch()) {
    var_dump($results);
}
```

Well, how can I access this array `[0]=>102, [1]=>64, [2]=>563, [3]=>79` before that `while()` in the above code?

**Note:** Preferably without the use of `fetchAll();`

Comment: well, you'll have to fetch them some way... there is no magic clairvoyance by which you can get it without those database functions. So either `fetchAll`, or a second loop based on `fetch`.

Comment: Use fetchAll(); and change `while` by `foreach` with that array ar `$results`

Comment: @splash58 I read somewhere `fetchAll()` consumes a lot of memory.. So I'm worry to use it.

Comment: Why do you need it there?

Comment: @AlexBlex In reality those numbers are `post_id` and I need those numbers to use them in another query to fetch all comments and then paste comments under its own post.

Comment: i think you can do this in mysql query

Comment: Fair enough, but  I fail to see what stops you to collect these codes into array within the `while` loop. btw, you may be able to fetch both posts and comments in a single query.

Comment: Ok I will try it. Thanks guys

Comment: @trincot You said: *"or a second loop based on `fetch`"*. Well how can I fetch a query twice?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9437214/resetting-array-pointer-in-pdo-results

Comment: @trincot Thanks *(I'd seen it before, though)* , that is `fetchAll()` ;-), I thought there is another way except `fetchAll`.. To be honest, I afraid to use `fatchAll`. I scare my memory get full quickly.

Comment: If you are going to read everything with fetch anyway, then there is little difference in terms of memory usage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is like saying *How can I fetch data without fetching it ?*

This is obviously impossible, you will need to fetch it at some point in your application.

---

```
if($results = $sth->fetch()) {
    var_dump($results);
}
```

Comment: Ok, what's your opinion about this: How can I fetch just one column of the result of a query?